# Is the set of non invertible matrices simply connected? What are their homotopy and homology groups?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology

It is fairly easy to see that the set of non invertible matrices is path connected. Are they simply connected? If not what is their fundamental group? What are their homotopy and homology groups. I'm looking for the answer to any of these questions. Any examples for particular (non 0 or 1) dimensions are welcome as well, as well as for real or complex coefficients.
(Sorry about the phrasing, it is currently 3:30 am and I will edit the question in the morning)

Comment: Matrices over what field or ring? And of what dimension?

Comment: With real or complex coefficients, and for any dimension you can show.

Comment: I'm mostly curious to know if they're simply connected, as my intuition is that the set looks like a bunch of lower dimensional vector spaces glued together at the origin

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The space of non-invertible matrices (with real or complex coefficients) is contractible. There is an explicit homotopy between the identity map and the constant map equal to the zero matrix, simply given by:
$$H(A,t) = tA.$$
In particular it is simply connected, and all its higher homotopy and homology groups vanish.

Comment: I didn't realize the space was star convex, I guess posting questions at 3am isn't the best idea.

Comment: @Liquid No big deal. When you learn all these sophisticated tools, the first impulse becomes to try using them, even though the answer is sometimes much simpler...

Comment: You are meaning the $0$ matrix and not the identity if I follow you well?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I mean that the identity $H(A,1) = A$ is homotopic to the constant map equal to the zero matrix $H(A,0) = 0$.

Comment: Understand thanks!

Comment: On the other hand, its compactly supported (co)homology is given by the (co)homology of $GL_n$, by Alexander duality.

Comment: This makes me wonder about the space of *non-zero* non-invertible matrices. Is that also contractible?

Comment: @TannerSwett I doubt it. In $M_1(\mathbb{R})$, the set of nonzero noninvertible matrices is empty, which is not contractible.

Comment: I think there's some confusion engendered by the fact that there's an identity *matrix*, and an identity *map*, so the term "identity" is ambiguous.

Comment: @Acccumulation I've clarified. But honestly, anyone familiar with the notion of homotopy and contractibility should be able to understand the first version of my answer.

Comment: It appears that we can conclude that either mathcounterexamples.net is not familiar with homotopy and contractibility, or your assertion is false.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi We can embed $\Bbb P^{n-1}\Bbb R$ into the set of nonzero noninvertible real matrices by sending a point in $\Bbb P^{n-1}\Bbb R$, i.e., a line in $\Bbb R^n$, to the orthogonal projection onto that line. Loosely speaking, the zero matrix is in the inside of this and hence we cannot have contractability.